# Smallest $n$ such that $p^n \nmid (p^2-1)!$

Tags: number-theory

Maybe trivial for number theorists, but not for me: is the title meaningful to ask for ($p$ is a prime)? If so, what's the answer?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is $n=p$.

To prove it we use the [de polignac formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) which in this case tells us:  $$v_p\left((p^2-1)!\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\Bigg\lfloor \frac {p^2-1}{p^i}\Bigg\rfloor=\Bigg\lfloor \frac {p^2-1}{p}\Bigg\rfloor= p-1$$

The claim follows immediately.

Comment: For $p=2$, we have $(p^2-1)!=3!=6$ which is not divisible by $2^2$. For $p=3$ we similarly get $3^3=27\not|40320=8!=(3^2-1)!$.

Comment: @Henrik Yes...both of which results support the claim.  Don't forget (as I did initially) that the OP is asking for the least exponent $n$ such that $p^n$ fails to divide.

Comment: Sorry, you're absolutely right, I just transformed it to the equivalent maximum exponent that does divide. (now I'm wondering if there's some corner cases where the two are not equivalent)

Comment: @Henrik  Yeah, that's what I did in the first version of my post.  The answers just differ by $1$, of course.

Comment: Thank you both, it really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As $p^2-1<p^2$, all the factors of $(p^2-1)!$ are smaller than $p^2$, and as $p$ is prime, that means the highest power of $p$ that divides any of the factors is $p$. It's not hard to see how many factors are divisible by $p$ giving the answer to your question.